# Minimum/maximum distance between points of $n$ disks

Tags: geometry, vectors, circles

Given $n$ disks with $n ≥ 2$, what's the minimum and maximum distance between any point within these disks?

For $n = 2$, the problem is fairly easy.

Consider two disks with $r_{1,2} = 1$ centered at $M_1(0|0)$ and $M_2(1, 0)$ respectively. [image: Two disks intersecting]

As they intersect, the minimum distance between any points within these disks is $d_{min} = 0$, and it's easy to see that the maximum distance is
$$d_{max} = \sqrt{({M_1}_x - {M_2}_x)^2 + ({M_1}_y - {M_2}_y})^2 + r_1 + r_2$$
In the example above, we have
$$d_{max} = \sqrt{(0-1)^2+(0-0)^2} + 1 + 1 = 3$$

If we shift $M_2$ to the right by two units, the disks don't intersect anymore:

[image: Two disks that don't intersect]

We now compute the minimum distance to be

$$d_{min} = \sqrt{({M_1}_x - {M_2}_x)^2 + ({M_1}_y - {M_2}_y})^2 - r_1 - r_2$$

With $M_2(3, 0)$, we then get:

$$d_{min} = \sqrt{(0 - 3)^2 + (0 - 0})^2 - 1 - 1 = 1$$

Now consider $n > 2$ disks.

[image: Three disks]

Clearly, $d_{min}$ and $d_{max}$ are not additive. Every neighboring disk has $d_{min} = 0$, but for the minimum distance from the leftmost disk to the rightmost, $d_{min} \neq 0$. A similar argument applies to $d_{max}$.

**Question: In general, what's the minimum/maximum distance between $n$ disks where $n > 2$?**

**Update**
This means: Given disks $D_1$ to $D_n$, I'm looking for the distances $d_{min}$ and $d_{max}$ for which there exists a set of points $P_1$ to $P_n$ where $P_i$ lies in $D_i$ and the length of the polygonal chain formed from $P_1$ to $P_n$ is minimal/maximal.

Comment: You should say that all your circles have the same radii.

Comment: @JeanMarie The radii can differ in my use case.

Comment: The minimum and maximum should  be the minimum and maximum, respectively, of the pairwise distances.

Comment: @quasi I don't think I'm looking for the distance you're describing. Given circles $C_1$ to $C_n$, I'm looking for the set of points $P_1$ to $P_n$ where $P_i$ lies in $C_i$ and the length of the line that $P_1$ to $P_n$ form is minimal/maximal, so every circle is "visited".

Comment: Then you should edit that into your question.

Comment: So for the minimum, you want the length of the shortest path which intersects each circle. Yes?

Comment: @quasi Exactly, yes. I've also updated the question.

Comment: A basic question : when you say "circle", do you really mean "circle" (the boundary of a disk, not its interior points) or disk (all points at a distance less than or equal to the radius) ?

Comment: The chosen points can be interior, so the sets are closed disks, not circles. Yes?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; interior points are allowed, so the intended notion was "disk". I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: You should not expect a formula. For a given set of disks, it's more of a sequence of nonlinear optimization problems. Try the 3-disk case, with a few random choices. You have the exact centers, and the exact radii. Set up the minimization/maximization algebraically, and see how it goes.  It will at least shed light on the general question. If there's a particular one of those you can't solve, ask it on MSE as a separate question (with a link back to this one).

Comment: For the minimization, it's a kind of Traveling Salesman Problem where you don't have to hit each city; you only have to get close (based on the specified radius for each). But for disjoint disks with radii approaching zero, it effectively _is_ the Traveling Salesman Problem. And for maximization, it's the _lazy_ Traveling Salesman Problem (if there is such a thing).

Comment: @quasi That makes sense, although I haven't looked at it like this yet; thanks for bringing this up!